# How to select only 1 record with sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a website like ebay with bids, I want to make a notifications mail for users who got outbidded

For example

- user 1 has a bid 11$
- user 2 has a bid 10$

I have a  table for bids:

```
 id  auction    bidder      bid  bidwhen         quantity  auto_bid  
 --  -------   ------  -------  --------------  --------  ----------
 1   150028       2  10.0000  20130719121024         0           0
 2   150028       1  11.0000  20130809122605         0           0
 3   150028       3  12.0000  20130809122605         0           0
```

and another table where I insert a winners like winner=3 with  =12

```
 id  auction  seller  winner     bid  closingdate        fee  quantity  
--  -------  ------  ------  ------  --------------  ------  ----------
 1   150028  1       3           12  20130809122658       1           1
```

If in our case id=3 is winner I need notificate id=2 that he is outbid and lost

I start with selecting winner and join bidders table but I can't figure out how to continue.

At the end I need get last ID before Winners ID  in our case bidder 1 cuz he bid last before winner

Comment: And where are you stuck?

Comment: provide some table structure data and maybe a query or whatever you tried so far.

Comment: Could you add your Sql queries here? That was its going to be easier to help. (I dont know why people downvote this question really)

Comment: Off-topic, because questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

Comment: i provide a table structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
SELECT ID
FROM Bids
WHERE auction = 150028
AND Bid < (SELECT MAX(Bid) FROM Bids WHERE auction = 150028)
ORDER By bid DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```

With this query you select the ID for a specific auction and get only the ID for the second highest bid.

**EDIT:**
For getting all auctions try the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT b1.ID
        FROM Bids b1
        WHERE b1.auction = b2.auction
        AND b1.Bid < (SELECT MAX(Bid) FROM Bids b3 WHERE b3.auction = b1.auction)
        ORDER By b1.bid DESC
        LIMIT 0,1) as ID, b2.auction
FROM Bids b2
```

Comment: but i not need for 1 auction ID i need for all auctions

Comment: im working on your second querry since 3 days bro , its work but when left join users there give false reuslt but when i didnt use join all is ok , how to join into this querry?

Comment: maybe you can open a new question where you can give a little more details what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To get last bidder before the winner

```
SELECT *
  FROM
(
  SELECT b.auction, MAX(b.bid) bid
    FROM bids b JOIN winners w
      ON b.auction = w.auction
     AND b.bidder <> w.winner
   GROUP BY b.auction
) q JOIN bids b
   ON q.auction = b.auction
  AND q.bid = b.bid
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09ba4/4)** demo

To get all bidders before the winner

```
SELECT *
  FROM bids b JOIN winners w
    ON b.auction = w.auction
   AND b.bidder <> w.winner
 -- WHERE b.auction = 150028 -- use if you need to fetch for particular auction
 ORDER BY b.auction, b.bid DESC
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09ba4/1)** demo

Comment: almost correct but i need the last bidder before winner not all bidders before winner

Comment: hm your updated answer is bring me a winner screen http://gyazo.com/24e734a727f967ebb9078abe73521e1e

Comment: sorry i fix it i have dublicatet some colums thats the answer thank you bro

Comment: can you explain me why we use  `MAX(b.bid)` and `AND b.bidder <> w.winner`

Comment: @AydınAleydin You're quite welcome :) With `b.bidder <> w.winner` we filter out all winners, then with `MAX(b.bid)` we grab the highest bid per auction which are effectively the ones that follow the winners.

Comment: when i have more than 1 more bidder this give me wrong result